# Mists of Pandaria Streaming

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Just wanted to let you all know that we're sponsoring [Midwinter Guild](http://www.mwguild.net/v4/) as they participate in 10-man and 25-man beta raiding for [Mists of Pandaria](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/).

They'll be raiding at 1:30pm and 7:00pm EST today at [www.twitch.tv/team/midwinter](http://www.twitch.tv/team/midwinter). They plan to stick around after the raids to do a live Q&A from viewers on chat (and possibly a giveaway!) if you want to check it out.

Enjoy!

Comment: +1 I'm glad to see we're branching out to even more gaming communities. Keep up the good work!

Comment: for teh horde!!

Comment: Just wondering, are they also going to participate on the site? Not that this would be necessary for promotion

Comment: @IvoFlipse we're brainstorming ways to get them involved in more cross promotion. Kicking around the idea of a podcast or contest for them and their viewers, but haven't settled on anything. Waiting for 25 man raids to begin.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that ended a long time ago and will never be "answered."